# SQLAlchemy - multiple subclass objects inheriting from the same instance of base object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to find a way to have multiple objects of a subclass inherit from the same instance of a base object.

I'm using a model from [SQLAlchemy's website](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/inheritance.html):

```
    from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
    from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
    from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped
    from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column
    
    class Base(DeclarativeBase):
        pass
    
    class Employee(Base):
        __tablename__ = "employee"
        id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
        name: Mapped[str]
        type: Mapped[str]
    
        __mapper_args__ = {
            "polymorphic_identity": "employee",
            "polymorphic_on": "type",
        }
    
        def __repr__(self):
            return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({self.name!r} {self.id!r})"
    
    class Engineer(Employee):
        __tablename__ = "engineer"
        id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("employee.id"), primary_key=True)
        engineer_name: Mapped[str]
    
        __mapper_args__ = {
            "polymorphic_identity": "engineer",
        }
    
    class Manager(Employee):
        __tablename__ = "manager"
        id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("employee.id"), primary_key=True)
        manager_name: Mapped[str]
    
        __mapper_args__ = {
            "polymorphic_identity": "manager",
        }
```

I can add a new object like:

```
    session.add(Manager(name='name1', manager_name="manager1"))
    session.commit()
```

Which creates a record in both Employee and Manager tables. Now, I would like to create an Engineer object which would reference the same Employee record as the Manager object just created. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What happens if you use a ManagerEngineer(Manager, Engineer) to complete the task?